# Execute code in custom Attribute before the MVC AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, action-filter

**The Problem**
Create a custom `IAuthorizeAttribute` which will execute before the default MVC AuthorizeAttribute. The default AuthorizeAttribute always seems to run before my custom attribute.

**Things I have tried**

- I made a custom attribute which inherits from IAuthorizationFilter.
- I've registered this attribute as a globalfilter like so:
  `filters.Add(new HandleCrossDomainAuthenticationAttribute() { Order = 1 });`
- I already read about action filters on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381609.aspx

**The custom attribute**

```
public class HandleCrossDomainAuthenticationAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    #region IAuthorizationFilter Members

    void IAuthorizationFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
        }

        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            tryCrossDomainAuthentication(filterContext); //this will set the filterContext.Result to a certain url
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

**Other observations**
When I specify an `Order = 2` on the `AuthorizeAttribute` that is giving me a hard time, It does work. But this is not a very manageable way to go...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must have read the msdn article the way I wanted it to be...

> The Order property takes an integer value that must be 0 (the default)
>   or greater, with one exception. Omitting the Order property gives the
>   filter an order value of -1, which indicates an unspecified order. Any
>   action filter in a scope whose Order property is set to -1 will be executed in an  undetermined order, **but *before* the filters that have a
>   specified order**.

So reading this, it seems to be impossible to do what I want unless you write a custom `AuthorizeAttribute` or a custom `ControllerActionInvoker`. That really sucks!

Comment: Why you just don't specify Order for both Authorize and your CustomAuthorize attribute ?

Comment: Because it forces me to specify the order for each authorize attribute and I have quite a few. It would be a lot more manageable if I could  keep that setting centralized.

Comment: @Peter define your own attribute inherited from AuthorizeAttribute and set Order to X at constructor, that will keep settings centralized